# Best solution for waiting on response in Android?

Tags: android, http, service

I want to create a Android background service, which creates a notification, if a server has restarted, but I need some ideas how to implement it.

I thought about a http connection, where the background service waits until a message comes in, but I think the connection can not be keep up while a restart. After this there came up a new idea, where the background service pushes a notification, when the connection breaks.

Would this be possible (if yes, what would be the easiest way) or is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: GCM / Firebase messaging / any Publish Subscribe system?

Answer (score 0):

Create an asynchronous task that tries to connect to the server in an endless loop. Use an time limit to cancel the process after a given time or return an ok value if the server responds an 200.